# Cant Change “Accept profile submissions from external sites” to No

Tags: profile, joomla, error, html

I'm getting two errors when logging into the Civi admin back-end. The first is

> Remote Profiles Enabled
>   Warning: External profile support (aka "HTML Snippet" support) is enabled in >system settings. This setting may be prone to abuse. If you must retain it, >consider HTTP throttling or other protections.

The second is

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in >/home/jgsny/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/>>check/Security.php on line 383

I navigate to system settings using the link in the error message which brings me to Misc settings page. The option "Accept profile submissions from external sites" is set to 'yes'. I change to 'no', save and return to the control panel, and the error message is gone.  However, on next login the error is back and the setting has reverted to 'yes'

Comment: I am getting the same msg "Remote Profiles Enabled
Warning: External profile support (aka "HTML Snippet" support) is enabled in system settings. This setting may be prone to abuse. If you must retain it, consider HTTP throttling or other protections." I upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.13, and navigated to system settings using the link in the error message which brings me to Misc settings page. The option "Accept profile submissions from external sites" is set to 'yes'. I change to 'no', save and return to the control panel, and the error message is gone. However, on next login the error is back and t

Comment: I just saw this warning on an upgraded site for first time. i set it to 'no' and saved, went back to Misc page and it remained set to 'no'. this was on 4.7.14

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a 4.6 site based on the second error message? If upgrading isn't possible you could try something like updating the database directly:

```
UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value='i:0;' where name='remote_profile_submissions';
```

Comment: We have been getting this in our site since September or so; we're currently on 4.6.24. There are 2 entries in civicrm_setting for remote_profile_submissions - one is set to '0' and one is set to '1'. Is it safe to delete one of these rows, or set both to '0'?
Thanks for any ideas anyone can offer.

Comment: Is the domain_id field different? - you might have multidomain set up. Pick the one with the domain_id that corresponds to the one you want. See the civicrm_domain table entries if you're not sure which is which. If they are the same domain_id, then it's a duplicate and one can be removed.

Comment: thanks Demerit! We only have one domain, so I'll go ahead and remove the duplicate.