# Can't find HTML Snippet in Profiles (Joomla)

Tags: profile, joomla, newsletter, form-snippets

I'm trying to add a newsletter sign-up form to an external* (Joomla) website. The guidance I've found online says that I should go to Customize » CiviCRM Profile, then click 'More' on right and select 'HTML Form Snippet', but it isn't there.

Does anybody know where it is?

*The CiviCRM installation is under a different Joomla site to the public one where the form's going.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable remote profiles.  **Administer menu » System Settings » Misc**.  Unfortunately, from your screenshot I see that you're running Civi 4.7.14.  That version has a known bug, where [remote profile setting can't be changed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/15131/12).

I would recommend upgrading to the latest 4.7 (this is a good idea anyway; 4.7.14 has known security bugs), then enable remote profile submission.

Comment: Sorted! I'd been putting off upgrading to 4.7.24 so it's probably good that something forced my hand.

Thanks for your help.